# I can't seem to install libsodium in the Docker ubuntu:vivid image

Tags: apt, docker

I installed software-properties-common then did the

```
add-apt-repository `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid universe
```

then tried `apt-get install libsodium` -- and that failed.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you meant `apt-get install libsodium13` or `apt-get install libsodium-dev` maybe ?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: remove  ` from   `deb  http:// .......    !!! it may be you have not added repo correctly . give error message that you get .

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libsodium&searchon=names&suite=vivid&section=all) or by:

```
$apt-cache search libsodium
libsodium-dbg - Network communication, cryptography and signaturing library - debug symbols
libsodium-dev - Network communication, cryptography and signaturing library - headers
libsodium13 - Network communication, cryptography and signaturing library
```

there is no package called `libsodium`. It is `libsodium13` or `libsodium-dev` or `libsodium-dbg`. So you should try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libsodium13
```

Comment: It says "unable to locate package: libsodium13" (after correcting the package name). The repo was added without any comments from the tool.

Comment: Here's the trace from the script that's doing the add repository:  
+ add-apt-repository deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu             vivid universe

I presume that the extra spaces in the quoted string are not significant.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to do an apt-get update. Sigh... The repository was already added in the docker image. Brain dead, apparently....

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is interested, and only just finding this post, I believe the newest version can be found as `libsodium18`

Comment: In its current form your answer is more of a comment. Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](https://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues. If you have a new question please [ask it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). - [from review](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/785850)